# How to drag body using AndEngine Box2D extension

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

Using AndEngine Physics Box2D i am trying to drag a body from side to side on the x axis.

This is what i have so far which isnt working correctly, the body moves up on the y axis and it doesnt follow the pointer(finger)

```
 int P2M = 32;
final Vector2 v2 = Vector2Pool.obtain(x / P2M, this.getY() / P2M);
body.setTransform(v2, 0); // if you want you can also set the rotation here
Vector2Pool.recycle(v2);
```

Anyone familiar with doing this?

Comment: how do you get x ? and what is your this object ?

Comment: use b2MouseJoint. It was designed do move objects with mouse/fingers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

probably you should use `body.getPosition().y` instead of `this.getY()` but I don't know how do you get x ? if you use `pSceneTouchEvent.getX()` then it sould works

Answer (score 1):

```
Vector2 localPoint = Vector2Pool.obtain((pTouchAreaLocalX/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT, (pTouchAreaLocalY/PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT);
body.setTransform(body.getWorldPoint(localPoint), 0);
Vector2Pool.recycle(localPoint);
```